# Hashing a struct in C

Tags: c, hash-map

I'm trying to learn how chained hashing works, but can't get any further than this. 
I think hashing works, but after finishing this little program, someone told me that what I have created so far has nothing to do with hashing.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define size 5
//This is my struct I wanted to add to the hashtable
struct customer{
    char name[20];
    int id;
    int pin;
    double money;
    struct customer *next;
};

//creating the table
struct customer *hash_table[size];
struct customer *next=NULL;
//my hashfunction
int hash_function(int id){
    unsigned int adress_hash;
    adress_hash = 31 * id;
    return adress_hash % 5;
}

//Adding the cust elements to my table
void add_customer(){
    int id_set = rand() % 8999 + 1000;
    struct customer *start;
    struct customer *pointer;
    int adress = hash_function(id_set);

     //first element

    if(hash_table[adress]==NULL)
    {
        hash_table[adress] = malloc(sizeof(struct customer));
        hash_table[adress]->id= id_set;
        hash_table[adress]->pin= rand() % 8999 + 1000;

        hash_table[adress]->money= 0;
        hash_table[adress]->next=NULL;
    } else {
        //Adding new files if the first element of the table is NOT NULL
        pointer=hash_table[adress];
        while(pointer->next != NULL)
        {
            pointer= pointer->next;
        }
        pointer->next = malloc(sizeof(struct customer));
        pointer=pointer->next;
        pointer->id=id_set;
        pointer->pin= rand() % 8999 + 1000;
        pointer->money = 0;

        pointer->next=NULL;
    }
}

void list_customer(int a){
    struct customer *pointer;
    int x;
    for(x=0;x<5;x++){
        pointer = hash_table[x];
        printf("%d. ----------\n", x);
        while(pointer != 0){
            printf("KNR: %d, PIN: %d\n", pointer->id, pointer->pin);
            pointer = pointer->next;
        }
        printf("-------------------------\n");
    }
}

int main(){
    int adr,x;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(x=0;x<5;x++){
        add_customer();
    }
    list_customer(size);
    getchar();getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think it would be good to use English for naming items, as that is the common way, plus it potentially allows for a better understanding of unclear parts by peers.

Comment: If what you have so far works, we can review it and suggest improvements. If it doesn't work, we cannot. We won't implement the missing features, but a review might still guide you in a good direction. So, does this work so far, and are you interested in a review?

Comment: I've edited the code and now it contains in-/ and output of data. I'd appreciate it if you can review this. The code I've created so far works.
I also don't wan't you to implement missing features. I just like to know, whether I understand the hashing princip and I'd like to have some suggests for improvements. :)

Answer (score 3):

I see a number of things that may help you improve your code.

### Understand the purpose of a hash table

The purpose of a hash table is as an associative array.  In this code, the `id` element of the `customer` structure is used as the hashed value and the hash function converts that int value into a number in the smaller range of `size`.  It's a valid use of a hash function and hash table.  The only thing missing is a means to actually use the hash function to quickly find a `customer` record.  To do that, you might implement a `find_customer` function that would search only in the appropriate "bucket" of the `hash_table` given the `id`.  With a large number of records \$n\$ where \$n \gg\$ `size`, this could save look-up time by needing to search only 20% of the records rather than all of them.  With that said, what follows is a review of the code you posted.

### Eliminate unused variables

The parameter `a` in the `list_customer()` function, `adr` in `main()`, and `start` in `add_customer()` are all unused variables and should be omitted from the program.

### Free allocated memory

Generally speaking, if you allocate memory using `malloc` or `calloc`, you should also `free` that memory to avoid "leaking" memory.

### Eliminate "magic numbers"

In a number of cases, the code uses "magic numbers" such as 8999 and 1000 that have no obvious meaning.  These would be better as named constants.  Also, a named constant `size` is already defined in the code, and should be used within `list_customer()` instead of hard coding `5`.

### Use better variable names

The names `hash_table` and `id` are good names, but `pointer` is not a good name because it is too generic.  I'd recommend something like `cust_ptr` (or `Kunde` if you prefer German).

### Declare variables in the smallest practical scope

By declaring variables in the smalles practical scope, you reduce the chance for name collisions and make it clear to the reader of your code where variables are and are not needed.  With any C compiler conforming to the 1999 specification (which should be all of them at this point!) one could rewrite `list_customer` like this for example:

```
void list_customer(){
    for(int x = 0; x < size; x++){
        printf("%d. ----------\n", x);
        for (struct customer *cust_ptr = hash_table[x];
                cust_ptr != NULL; cust_ptr = cust_ptr->next)
        {
            printf("KNR: %d, PIN: %d\n", cust_ptr->id, cust_ptr->pin);
        }
        printf("-------------------------\n");
    }
}
```

Note also that I have converted your `while` loop into a `for` loop which I think clarifies the nature of the code.

### Check the return value of `malloc`

If the system is running out of memory, `malloc` will return `NULL`.  Code **must** check the return value to make sure it is not `NULL` before dereferencing the variable or the program will crash.

### Avoid repeating code

Two places in the code use the construct `rand() % 8999 + 1000` which suggests that they should probably be made into a function or macro.

### Functions taking no parameter should be declared `void`

A function declared as `void add_customer()` in C may actually take any number of parameters which is an old misfeature of the C language.  What you probably want instead is to declare it as taking no parameters which is done like this:

```
void add_customer(void)
```

### Create subfunctions to keep the code clear and neat

The `add_customer()` code needs to create a new customer and then put it into the `hash_table`.  We can delegate the creation to a separate function:

```
struct customer *new_customer(int id)
{
    struct customer *cust_ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct customer));
    if (cust_ptr != NULL) {
        cust_ptr->name[0] = '\0';
        cust_ptr->id = id;
        cust_ptr->pin = myrand();
        cust_ptr->money = 0;
        cust_ptr->next = NULL;
    }
    return cust_ptr;
}
```

Note that this code initializes the `name` member which the original code did not.  Now the `add_customer` code can be much simpler:

```
void add_customer(void){
    int id_set = myrand();
    int adress = hash_function(id_set);
    struct customer *cust_ptr = hash_table[adress];
    if (cust_ptr == NULL) {
        hash_table[adress] = new_customer(id_set);
        return;
    } 
    while(cust_ptr->next != NULL) {
        cust_ptr = cust_ptr->next; 
    }
    cust_ptr->next = new_customer(id_set);
}
```

And of course the `myrand()` function:

```
int myrand(void) 
{
    return rand() % 8999 + 1000;
}
```

### Omit `return 0` at the end of `main`

The compiler will automatically generate the equivalent to `return 0` for code that successfully gets to the end of `main`.